# Writing to a file in a for loop and def is not defined

Tags: python

In Python, This can not loop many times and cannot find ID number in def.

Every time I try to run the program I get the error

> "NameError: name 'askname' is not defined"

and in textfile Keep only the latest data

- I expect the output of `#def new_booking` to be Keep data in files continuously but the actual output is kept data in files just one sentence
- I expect the output of #def pre_booked to be Extract data from a file but the actual output is

> "NameError: name 'askname' is not defined"

```
import random

# total=0
# people=0
total1 = 0
total2 = 0


# mini bar
def mini_bar():
    mini_bar_total = 0
    print("£50 for the Bar")
    askbar = input("Would you like a mini bar? Y/N")
    if askbar.upper() == "Y":
        mini_bar_total = mini_bar_total + 50
    return mini_bar_total


# breakfast
def breakfast(people, asknights):
    breakfast_total = 0
    print("£25 for breakfast")
    askdinner = input("Would you like dinner? Y/N")
    if askdinner.upper() == "Y":
        breakfast_total = (people * 25) * asknights
        print("total: £", breakfast_total)
    return breakfast_total


# dinner
def dinner(people, asknights):
    dinner_total = 0
    print("£25 for Dinner")
    askdinner = input("Would you like dinner? Y/N")
    if askdinner.upper() == "Y":
        dinner_total = (people * 25) * asknights
    return dinner_total


# number customers
def num_customers():
    customer_total = 0
    print("£50 an Adult")
    askadult = int(input("How many adults? "))
    customer_total = askadult * 50
    print("total: £", customer_total)
    print("£25 a Child")
    askchild = int(input("How many children? "))
    customer_total = (askchild * 25) + customer_total
    print("total: £", customer_total)
    return customer_total, askadult, askchild


# number of nights (multiplier)
def num_nights(customer_total):
    nights_total = 0
    waiting = True
    while waiting == True:
        try:
            asknights = int(input("How many nights are you staying for? "))
            nights_total = customer_total * asknights
            print("total: £", nights_total)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("invalid input!")
    return nights_total, asknights


# New Booking *********
def new_booking():
    askname = str(input("Please enter your name? "))
    idnumber = random.randint(100, 999)
    customer_total, numAdults, numChild = num_customers()
    Num_people = numAdults + numChild
    nights_total, asknights = num_nights(customer_total)
    askbar = mini_bar()
    askbreakfast = breakfast(Num_people, asknights)
    askdinner = dinner(Num_people, asknights)
    total = askdinner + askbreakfast + askbar + asknights
    detailslist = (idnumber, askname, numAdults, numChild, asknights, askbar, askbreakfast, askdinner)
    for i in detailslist:
        f = open('newbooking.txt', 'w')
        f.write(str(detailslist) + '\n')
        print(i)
    print("your total amount is: £", total)
    print("your Name & ID number is: ", askname, idnumber)

# Pre booking ***** is not defind
def pre_booked():
    name = input("enter your name or ID number: ")
    if name == (askname) or (idnumber):
        detailslist = [idnumber, askname, askadult, askchild, asknights, askbar, askbreakfast, askdinner]
        for i in detailslist:
            print(i)
        print("total: £", total)

# main menu, start of program.
def main_menu():
    print("##################### WELCOME TO BAY HOTEL ###########################")
    print('''Please see what is available at the Hotel,\nAdult Prices per night: £50pp,\nChild price: £25pp,\nMiniBar price: £50 per room,\nBreakfast: £20pp,\nDinner: £25pp''')
    while True:
        prebook = input("Have you booked? Y/N")
        if prebook.upper() == "N":
            new_booking()
        elif prebook.upper() == "Y":
            pre_booked()


main_menu()

- I expect the output of #def new_booking to be Keep data in files continuously but the actual output is keep data in files just one sentence
- I expect the output of #def pre_booked to be Extract data from file but the actual output is "NameError: name 'askname' is not defined"
```

Comment: Hy flying 39, this is a lot of code to review. To make it easier for the community, could you please consider reducing it and focusing on the parts most relevant to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your way to writing data in files.

Working with files has 3 step:

1) Opening file

2) Read [from] / Write [to] file

3) Closing file

third step is what you don't handled it.

You want to write a list in file and you are opening that file in each iteration. It's not a good idea (opening and closing files have their overhead) when you can do it once.

I changed some of your `new_booking` function and wrote it here:

```py
# New Booking *********
def new_booking():
    askname = str(input("Please enter your name? "))
    idnumber = random.randint(100, 999)
    customer_total, numAdults, numChild = num_customers()
    Num_people = numAdults + numChild
    nights_total, asknights = num_nights(customer_total)
    askbar = mini_bar()
    askbreakfast = breakfast(Num_people, asknights)
    askdinner = dinner(Num_people, asknights)
    total = askdinner + askbreakfast + askbar + asknights
    detailslist = (idnumber, askname, numAdults, numChild, asknights, askbar, askbreakfast, askdinner)

    # I handled opening and closing file with [python with statement]
    # It close files automatically at the end
    with open('newbooking.txt', 'w') as f:    
        for i in detailslist:
            f.write(str(detailslist) + '\n')
            print(i)
    print("your total amount is: £", total)
    print("your Name & ID number is: ", askname, idnumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you havent actually defined askname in your `pre_booked()` function so you cant compare against it. In `new_booking()` you are asking for the username with `askname = str(input("Please enter your name? "))` however in the `pre_booked()` case you dont so you cant use it there without first getting the values from somewhere.

Seeing that you save the `new_booking()` to a file you probably want to load the data from your file like this:

```
accounts = []
with open(r"<FILEPATH", "r") as booking_file:
   for line in booking_file:
       accounts.append(line)
```

In your new_booking function it might be better to put all the related data in line by line or maybe even use dicts so you can later be sure which values belong together instead of writing all the values into their own line. So you might want to do this instead:

```
with open('newbooking.txt', 'w') as booking_file:    
    f.write(detailslist)
```

Then you can read line by line and possibly use ´eval()´ to get a list or dictionary right from your string or atleast you know the values in one line belong together later on.

You might also want to consider using "a" for append instead of w for write in your bookings file depending if you want to have multiple booking values in your file or just the one.